# NextJS Inverted Colours on Mobile Device (Brave Browser)

Tags: next.js, colors, brave

I'm building a site using NextJS for my wedding this year and when deployed, it's appearing differently per browser. Safari renders fine, but Brave inverts all the colours (changing white to black).

None of my css would've affected this - any ideas?